# Reputation chart on profile page is cut off on right side

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-interface, reputation-graph

The chart to display the reputation of a user in its profile is cut off on the right side, so that the last bar is smaller than the others bars in the chart.

[image]

I check this with Chrome 25.0.1364.172 and FireFox 19.0.2.

Comment: It's the correct width for half a day.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson or its a sliding window view that moves to the left when time increases

Comment: Given that the *left most* bar is *also* cut, I'm inclined to assume that this is a deliberate choice - but I will check.

Comment: @MarcGravell: do you made changes to the chart? Cause bug seems to be fixed.

Comment: @Marc did you check it by now? It was just [reported again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215033/reputation-bar-width-of-last-bar-is-small).

Comment: @AlienArrays it's 43 weeks by now, bit more than the standard 6-8 weeks we always have to wait. ;)