# Width of the last reputation bar is small

Tags: support, bug, reputation, reputation-graph

The following is the screenshot of my reputation bar graph on Stack Overflow on 2014-01-05.

[image: Reputation bar chart 05-01-2014(d-m-y)]

and on 2014-01-06 it is displayed as :

[image: Reputation bar chart 06-01-2014(d-m-y)]

In the first screenshot reputation bar chart you can see that the last bar on the right side has less width than the bars before it, but in the second screenshot the last bar has same width as others. I just want to know if there's a specific reason why it appears like that or is it because of the display bug.

Just want to know. It would be nice to get any information regarding it.

Comment: which browser you producing this?

Comment: Ok @ShadowWizard i didnt see that question page when i searched google.May be the words that i entered didnt match.But it doesnt have an answer .If you know why its displayed like that can you answer?

Comment: These are the cases where duplicates are useful; where the original cannot easily be found

Comment: @Zword don't know, it might be by design but also might be a bug, as Marc (SE dev) said in the first report.

Comment: Mine has [extra space](http://i.3ventic.eu/2014010608475728.png) to the right of today (marked with arrow)

Comment: @3ventic see my second image .It also has a space on the right side.Is it display bug?

Comment: It's interesting for sure.

Comment: I think for each day the graph shifts to the left in such a way that on one day the last bar width appears to be small and on the day next to it it appears with equal width with a space at its left for the coming day reputation. Do all agree with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i think the following can be the answer for the question that i asked,so i am answering the question myself:

I think for each day the graph shifts to the left in such a way that if on a day the last bar width appears to be small then on the day next to it, last bar in graph appears with normal width with a space at its left to accommodate the coming day's reputation.

Comment: Please all comment to let me know if my answer could be the reason for graph appearance change on adjacent days. When i am sure that one from the two answers currently posted is correct i will accept that as answer.

Comment: I am talking about the graph. I said the graph shifts to the left making the last bar width to appear small.